# Macos crash report shows a thread id / number that is different from posix thread id

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos

I have a Macos application that is crashing, I'm trying to analyze the crash report and I see that a certain thread is the one that keeps on crashing in all of the reports.

Trying to associate that thread to my application thread, the report shows threads numbers (0 as main thread, thread 1, 2 and so on)

and they are totally different number from the thread ID I get from *pthread_self / pthread_threadid_np*

Anyway to connet between these number so I can find the problematic thread in my app ?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73538777/map-pthread-t-to-linux-thead-id ?

Comment: Seems like its linux specific, doesnt work for Macos